# How do I diagnose this hard drive or motherboard issue?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, laptop-repair

I am having a weird issue with a laptop I am fixing (let's call this laptop Broken). I used a second, working laptop to diagnose issues (let's call this laptop Working)

I got Broken, and the HDD didn't seem to be recognized by the BIOS. I swapped the Broken's hard drive for the one from Working. Broken didn't recognize Working's hard drive. So I figured it wasn't the hard drive and was some other electronic issue instead. With laptops, I typically just recommend replacing the whole thing.

So I went to back up the Broken's hard drive, but when I plug it into Working, it just beeps at me. Seems like I have both a board AND hard drive issue.

What could this be? It seems unlikely I have two independent failures at once. Perhaps I am missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a second computer. Connect the old drive to it to see if it's recognized. My guess is that you probably do have a mobo failure of some sort, but it's manifesting in different ways (sometimes HDD not recognized, sometimes it recognizes but beeps.)

However, it's also possible, although very unlikely, that you have two independent failures. That's why you'll need another computer to verify.

Comment: OK. So I have two computers, which was in my original question, but I have updated the question to make this more clear because I see now I wasn't getting my point across...

Comment: @JakeGould Only after the edit. The original post didn't mention a second computer.

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshooting these kind of problems is simply isolating a common point of failure. If there is not a single common point of failure, then that could indicate potentially multiple points of failure. I would keep that in mind when trying to figure out a problem.

The fact that you can access the BIOS in the old system is good. This means that the motherboard is likely still good to some extent. See if you can find information in the BIOS that indicates your CPU and Memory are good. If it appears to be just the HDD that's bad, try booting from a disc or USB. For these kind of problems, I always have a copy of the [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/download.html) to test with.

Some other ideas:

- Check the POST code of the working system with the HDD from the broken system, does it indicate HDD failure? If not, what does it indicate? If you accidentally unseated some RAM, for example, it could look like HDD failure when it is actually something else.
- The SATA cable used to connect the HDD could have gone out, or the connector on the motherboard could be damaged somehow. For that, I would check with a known-good cable.
- The broken system could be failing to provide power to the HDD, do you hear it physically spin up?
- A power surge or the battery shorting out could cause damage to multiple components. It's entirely possible that you have several dead components from the same incident.